# Manually interacting with postfix mail queue

Tags: email, postfix

I need to manually be able to interact (check, remove, etc) with the postfix mail queue (through scripts and what-not). I know that this generally is a bad idea; so how can I interact with the queue without screwing things up?

I believe one possible solution is to shutdown postfix, do work on the queue, and then start postfix?

Comment: Why do you think that's a bad idea?

Comment: "without screwing things up" sort of implies "use the tools provided" rather than manually fudging stuff. Are there specific things you'd want to do that you can't do with the tools postfix provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two commands: `postqueue` and `postsuper`. Check man page for this commands.

Comment: There is also `postcat`. @josten, have your tools call `postqueue`, `postsuper`, and `postcat`.